# Is there any workaround for fetching Facebook birthday events in newer versions of Graph API?

Tags: python, facebook, python-3.x, facebook-graph-api

I am writing a Python script and I need to fetch the birthday events appearing on side bar. Since v2.0 of the Graph API, **it´s not possible** to fetch birthday from your friend list but is there any workaround for fetching birthday event that appears only in side bar and not for the whole friend list.

**Is there any way to do it without graph API ?**

[image]

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use open graph api to fetch the information from your friend list. The birthday is in the user information object, see docs: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user

Comment: Since v2.0 of the Graph API, it´s not possible to fetch birthday from your friend list that is why I was asking if there is any workaround for finding birthday that appear only in side bar and not for the whole friend list.

See the changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog